# Что делает строка return -1?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, что в данном коде делает return - 1 строка 8

```js
function findCarInLot(car) {
  for (var i = 0; i < lot.length; i++) {
    if (car === lot[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;

}

var chevy = {
  make: "Chevy",
  model: "Bel Air"
};

var taxi = {
  make: "Webville Motors",
  model: "Taxi"
};

var fiat1 = {
  make: "Fiat",
  model: "500"
};


var fiat2 = {
  make: "Fiat",
  model: "500"
};

var lot = [chevy, taxi, fiat1, fiat2];

var loc1 = findCarInLot(fiat2);
var loc2 = findCarInLot(taxi);
var loc3 = findCarInLot(chevy);
var loc4 = findCarInLot(fiat1);

console.log(loc1);
console.log(loc2);
console.log(loc3);
console.log(loc4);
```

Comment: возвращает -1 ?

Comment: А зачем это здесь? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция возвращает индекс найденного элемента.

А в случае неудачи - элемент не найден - возвращает -1.

Такое соглашение нередко используется.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. В случае неудачи "else" можно не прописывать?

Comment: А при таком поиске else и некуда прописывать, ведь if применяется к каждому элементу по очереди

Comment: Если сделать так, например?

function findCarInLot(car) {
  for (var i = 0; i < lot.length; i++) {
    if (car === lot[i]) {
      return i;
    } else {
return -1;
  }

}

Comment: В таком случае первый элемент не совпадает - вернули -1, а второй-то и не проверили

Comment: Все ясно теперь! ) Спасибо!

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос ) Почему return -1 не перезаписывает результат проверки for if ? )

Comment: При успехе проверки return немедленно выходит из функции, до -1 тогда дело не дойдёт

Comment: Спасибо! Ясно )